# Why does Base *pd = new Derived; generate an error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, new-operator

Given this code:

```
class Base{ 
public: 
    Base(); 
    virtual ~Base(); 
}; 

class Derived: protected Base{ 
public: 
    virtual ~Derived(); 
};
```

In main I am trying to assign derived to base in this way:

```
Base *pd = new Derived;
```

Why is this statement generating an error?

Here new will return a pointer of the object type and we can always assign a derived pointer to a base. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No code?! there can be any number of errors...

Comment: Probably because you aren't declaring `Derived : Base`

Comment: This should work, yes. The most obvious solution is the one given by @BoltClock. Derived must inherit Base in the first place. If this is not the case, please offer some code that would enable someone to diagnose the issue. Also, what's the error message?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete Question but here is what i am trying to do 

class Base{                                                                               

public: 

Base(); 

virtual ~Base(); 

}; 

class Derived: protected Base{ 

public: 

virtual ~Derived(); 

};

Comment: `protected` inheritance is almost entirely different from `public` inheritance.

Comment: If you say "generating an error" it is usually helpful if you provide the text of the error so that answerers can know what problem they are trying to solve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To convert a pointer to one class to a pointer to a different class type the conversion must be accessible at the point that it is invoked.

As `Base` is a protected base of `Derived` you can't initialize a variable of type `Base *` from the expression `new Derived` (which has type `Derived *`) outside of a member function of `Derived`, a class derived from it or a `friend` of `Derived`.

Comment: but even by making it a public inheritance i am getting a link error..saying unreferenced call for both cont and destructor in derived class...LNK2019

Comment: class Base{ 
public: 
Base(); 
virtual ~Base(); 
}; 
class Derived: protected Base{ 
public: 
virtual ~Derived(); 
}; 
int main() 
{ 
Base *pd = new Derived; 
return 0; 
}

Comment: @Srikanth Reddy: That's because you haven't *implemented* the constructor(s) and destructors.

Answer (score 0):

A linker error may just be the result of missing an implementations for the classes.  It would help if you could post the particular error messages.